# Jquery using append/appendTo with time delay

Tags: html, jquery, css

```
function a(response) {
   setTimeout(function () {
          for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                if (response[i].hasOwnProperty("text")) {
                    var b = '<img class="img" src="path of my pic"/><p class="someclass">' + response[i].text + '</p><div class="something"></div>';             
                    $(b).appendTo(".chatwindow").hide().fadeIn(1000);
                } } } }
```

How do I use appendTo/append the content one after the other with a time delay? Instead it is displaying all at once, which I dont want like that.Please help me if i have to change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method for this:

```js
function appendWithDelay() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var template = '<img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100"/>';
    $(template).hide().appendTo(".chatwindow").delay(i * 1000).fadeIn(1000);
  }
}

appendWithDelay();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chatwindow"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Place your settimeout function inside the loop and condition

```
function a(response) {
    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        if (response[i].hasOwnProperty("text")) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var b = '<img class="img" src="path of my pic"/><p class="someclass">' + response[i].text + '</p><div class="something"></div>';
                $(b).appendTo(".chatwindow").hide().fadeIn(1000);
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need `1000 * i` otherwise they still all run at the same time